# Open GL error after SDWebImage download in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, sdwebimage

I'm downloading a image using SDWebImage inside a init for a layer.

Something like this:

```
    NSURL *thumbnailURL = playerFacebookID.stringValue;        
    [[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] downloadWithURL:thumbnailURL
                                              delegate:self
                                               options:0
                                               success:^(UIImage *image) {
                                                   CCTexture2D *texture = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithCGImage:[[image resizeAndCropToSize:CGSizeMake(kThumbnailSizeInPixels, kThumbnailSizeInPixels)] CGImage] resolutionType:kCCResolutioniPhone];
                                                   localPlayerThumbnail.texture = texture;
                                                   [texture release];
                                               }
                                               failure:nil];
```

The image loads fine and works, but I get Open GL errors, for a little while after the block kicks in, stuff like this:

```
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCSprite draw] 544
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCSprite draw] 544
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCTextureAtlas drawNumberOfQuads:fromIndex:] 556
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCTextureAtlas drawNumberOfQuads:fromIndex:] 556
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCSprite draw] 544
```

Now the weird thing is even if I remove the code inside the block, basically have the return block from SDWebImageManager do nothing, it still gives the error messages. So it's not related to the loading of the texture or any of those resize functions.

The only thing I can think at the moment is that somehow the SDWebImageManager is changing the Open GL context, or doing something that is interrupting Cocos2d draw calls.